# How to get the label in my automated dropdown location in laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, laravel

I only get the code on a particular province,city and barangay not the exact label or name of the province,city and barangay.[image][image][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bal8I.png)

I try to enter the id of province, city and barangay for example is <option value"barangay"> Please Select

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to get the label not the code of its place. For example when I choose Caloocan City in dropdown it will show in my database as Caloocan City.